# Jquery $(document).ready return ERROR: "This is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery script which return

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

below is the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  console.log("jimmy"); 

});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery?

Comment: Yes i have at the top

Comment: So this is at the bottom right? Can you share the full code?

Comment: This is a very long code as its in joomla admin code

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery is being pointed to correctly?

Comment: Yes the script is between `<body></body>`

Comment: Try replacing with `jQuery(document)...`

Comment: Check in your browser console if jQuery is being loaded.

Comment: Maybe load your jQuery in the `<head>` instead of the body.

Comment: I guess so seince all other animation are loading correctly , is ther a way i can test if the jquery is loaded correctly

Comment: @jimmyobonyo check your network console; and where the script is loaded?

Comment: using `jQuery` insted of `$` works

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using `jQuery` over `$` works, it means your `$` is being used by Joomla or Drupal.  You can still use `$` within your code though:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  // notice the $

   $('selector'); // can use $

});
```

---

*While the jQuery documentation may talk about performing this approach when other libraries exist, I find it easier to do by default.  It clearly shows that you are using* jQuery *and shows that `$` is passed as an argument.  There's also less* magic *that a new programmer may not understand, and so they can more easily trace problems back to the documentation, rather than first having to find out what `$` may point to.*

Comment: Would you need to call `$.noConflict();` above the `.ready()`, or would it work as is?

Comment: noConflict is generally used to release control.  So if you loaded Prototype, then loaded jQuery, calling noConflict would return the `$` back to the Prototype library.  That way you could use both jQuery and Prototype together.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the clarification!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that there may be time where for whatever reason you have two different versions of jQuery on the same page (for instance if something was deprecated).  This case is generally rare and ill-advised, but to compensate, there are other arguments you can pass in order to use/manage more than one version of jQuery within the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, for some reason, u don't have $ assigned or exists some incompatibility with another library.

If that's the case, u could use:

```
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score -2):

First, add jQuery into body :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And **only after that**, add your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  console.log("jimmy"); 

});
</script>
```

Full code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Content of your website
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

          console.log("jimmy"); 

        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now it's ok ?

Comment: Jquery is being loaded , check question comment

Comment: using `jQuery` insted of `$ `works

Comment: If so you have some conflicts between jQuery and another library. Use noConflict(). See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score -2):

using `jQuery` insted of `$` makes the script  works